# Main query results in Subquery

Tags: sql

How can we use reference of main query result set as a source table in subquery

Table A, Table C

```
Select 
       (Select * From a) 
  From 
       (Select tabA.* 
          From A tabA 
          Join C tabC 
            On tabA.id = tabC.id) as a
```

I got invalid object a error here

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want a common table expression (CTE):

```
with a as (
      select tabA.*
      from A tabA Join
           C tabC
           on tabA.id = tabC.id
     )
Select (Select * from a)
From a;
```

That said, your query makes no sense.  The scalar subquery is probably going to be returning an error, either because of the number of rows or number of columns.

Comment: Is it fast enough on processing over millions of data. While I am using the Reference two - three times in nested query?

Comment: @Abhishek . . . If you have a *performance* question, then ask another question, with a better description of what you are doing and an appropriate database tag.  This question is quite clearly about syntax and has been answered (more than once).

Answer (score 0):

if you using sqlserver than modified your query based on below query.

select * from 
(select A.* from TableA A inner join TableB B on A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID )  a